# ASP.ne MVC Return to pervious page after submitting form _ index action overload for httppst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I Have a Form that I want to return to previous Page after submitting.

everything works correctly but I have a question of how to overload index

Create action redirect to index action of `Tour Controller`
here is my `index` action

```
public ActionResult Index(string country)
    {

        if (country == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        }

        Country c = db.Countries.Where(e => e.CountryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower()).First();

        ViewBag.ResultMessage = TempData["ResultMessage"];
        ViewBag.Country = c.CountryName;
        TempData["Country"] = c.CountryName;
        var tours = db.Tours.Where(e => e.CountryId == c.Id);

        var vm = new TourRequestViewModel { Tours = tours.ToList(), Request = new Models.Request() };

        return View(vm);

    }
```

My question is how I can have an `overload` for `index` with `[HttpPost]` with same arguments(if possible somehow) or how to change arguments that I can set an [HttpPost]overload for index method.

My Create action If needed :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,TourId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Comment,FrequentTraveler,TravelersCount,Date,ContactTimePreference,Country,Archived")] Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Form  Posted successfully.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = TempData["Country"] });
        }
        TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Try Again!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = TempData["Country"] });
    }
```

my Route Config if needed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "TourRoute",
           url: "{country}/tours",
           defaults: new { controller = "Tour", action = "Index" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Appreciate you help.

Comment: What do you mean _overload the Index method_? And why do you think you would need to? And why are you using `TempData` here? Its very unclear what you trying to do.

Comment: Because I uploaded My project to server and after posting form my index page is not finding (Error 404) but when its offline it works fine. I thought it needs to be Htttppost. and for `TempData` I needed to save name of country to get back to page of that main country and view bag was not helpful so I used `TempData` that's not correct? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No its not. I thought I explained this in a previous chat. Your `Request` model appears to contain a property named `Country` so when you initialize your view model in the GET method, set the value - `var vm = new TourRequestViewModel { Tours = tours.ToList(), Request = new Models.Request(){ Country = country} };` and then generate a hidden input for `Country` in the view, and then its just `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = request.Country });` in the POST method

Comment: Thank you I will try it thanks again

Comment: wooow it works but i didn't understand what happens exactly need to think much more but if its possible please answer that previous message . thank u thousand times  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245394/asp-net-mvc-return-to-same-view-after-action-create?noredirect=1#comment63913273_38245394    @StephenMuecke

Comment: any time thanks really so much . @StephenMuecke

Comment: I have answered this one rather than the other (they are both asking essentially the same thing but this one is clearer). I suggest you delete the other question)

Comment: you are right thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `[Bind]` attribute on the POST method indicated that `Request` has a property named `Country`, so you just need to set that value in the GET method

```
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
    if (country == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Country c = db.Countries.Where(e => e.CountryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower()).First();
    ViewBag.ResultMessage = TempData["ResultMessage"];
    var vm = new TourRequestViewModel
    {
        Tours = db.Tours.Where(e => e.CountryId == c.Id).ToList(),
        Request = new Models.Request
        {
            Country = country
        }
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Side note: Your `Country c = db.Countries.Where(...).First();` will throw an exception is the country does not exist. You should be using `.FirstOrDefault()` and checking if its `null` (and return a NotFound or BadRequest if its is)

Then in the view, inside the form for `Request`, add a hidden input for the Country

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Country)
```

and then finally, change the POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create (Request request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Requests.Add(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Form  Posted successfully.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = request.Country });
    }
    TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Try Again!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = request.Country });
}
```

Side note: If `ModelState` is not valid, you should not be redirecting to the `Index()` method. Instead, return the view so that validation errors are shown and the user can correct the data. Currently, a new blank form is displayed to the user and they have no idea what they did wrong.

Comment: really thank you for this complete answer. now everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult Index(TourRequestViewModel model)
{

  return View();
}
```

You mean ?

Comment: exactly and I don't know how to match all these things. I want to call this index from my `create` action what should I write exactly? for return redirect to action?

Comment: You don't need to create method.using by index overloaded you can do read/write operation.but u can use redirecttoaction and passing parameter to it.

Comment: when my project is offline it works fine but I upload it and after posting it hast 404 error . I thought it surely needs [HttpPost]. you dont think so?

Comment: I,don't think,I think The problem is somewhere else.